# Why are there different classes of titans?

Tags: attack-on-titan

There are 4 size classes of titans.

[image]

<sup>Taken from [Shingeki no Kyoujin Wiki](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130527182654/shingekinokyojin/images/thumb/5/56/Maru1369501858577.png/1000px-Maru1369501858577.png)</sup>

Why is this so? Do they get larger when they eat?

Comment: It'll also be good to know why there is such a huge difference between 60m and 15m

Comment: This hasn't even been fully answered in the manga yet, as it turns out.

Answer (score 4):

**Spoiler alert!**

> The classes are just sizes and nothing more. However, the 60 m class is not really a class but is classified as *special* or *abnormal* much like Eren and Annie. These specials are basically one of a kind titan that have different abilities like jumping and running. We see them several times in the series.

Comment: but then there are these guys: http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_Titan which makes 60m not unique.

Comment: Wow I didn't notice that... thank you. Hmm but although it would seem that way the 60 m is taller then the ones in the wall so maybe they are just another class like a 40 m one. To me it doesn't really make sense of why they are in the walls. Maybe we will later find out. But then again don't forget that the 60 m titan can apear and disappeare out of thin air like Eren and Annie so that would still make it abnormal because all the others including the ones in the wall can't do that from what I can tell

Comment: @bmrm145 It has been explained in the latest few chapters.

Answer (score 1):

I forget which chapter when it happened. Spoiler alert.

> When the Marleyan army went to Paradis Island to turn the members of Eldian Restoration Movement into mindless titan, I thought they said that the serum can determine which class of titan they will be.

Comment: That is a end of anime season 3 spoiler FYI, which happened around chap 85-90